# Euler Totient Integer Remainder Sum Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

My question was:

Prove that the sum of the remainder of  $N$ divided by $\phi(N-1)$ and the remainder of the division of  $N - 1$ by $\phi(N)$  is always odd for $N \gt 3$.

This is my attempt thus far:

let the sum of remainder of $N$  divided by $\phi(N - 1)$ and the remainder of $N - 1$ divided   by $\phi(N)$ be $S_N$.

knowing that one of terms of $S_N$ must be:

$$s_0=2\Bigl\lfloor-\frac {1}{2}\Bigr(\Bigl\lfloor\frac {N}{\phi(N-1)} \Bigr\rfloor\phi(N-1)-1+\Bigl\lfloor \frac {N-1}{\phi(N)}\Bigr\rfloor\phi(N)\Bigl)\Bigr\rfloor$$

and from the observation such a term is clearly an even number,we then deduce that the sum of the remaining terms must be odd in order for the sum $S_N$ to be odd. 
Denoting all remaining terms collectively as $s_1$:

$$s_1=\Bigl(\frac {N}{\phi(N-1)}-\Bigl\lfloor\frac {N}{\phi(N-1)} \Bigr\rfloor\Bigr)\phi(N)+\Bigl(\frac {N-1}{\phi(N)}-\Bigl\lfloor\frac {N-1}{\phi(N)} \Bigr\rfloor\Bigr)\phi(N-1)-1$$

We can therefore say that if  $s_1$ is an odd number,$S_N$ is then the sum of an odd and even number, therefore also odd.

knowing $ \phi(N-1)$ & $\phi(N)$ to always be even numbers for all $N \gt 3$ affirms that $s_1$ is indeed odd, therefore we can now conclude that $S_N$ is also odd for all $N \gt 3$.

Comment: It seems a bit long-winded, but at the end it boils down to the observation that the remainder of a number $n$ modulo an even $m$ always has the same parity as $n$, and since totients (except for $\varphi(1) = \varphi(2) = 1$) are even, and exactly one of $N$ and $N-1$ is odd, the sum of the remainders is odd. But what precisely is your question? Whether your argument is correct?